# I cant install any new updates i get the error dpkg: error: info database format (2) is bogus or too new; try getting a newer dpkg

Tags: 14.04, dpkg, update-manager

arun@arun-RD405-L-CDA1A2:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  flashplugin-installer google-chrome-stable grub-common grub-pc grub-pc-bin
  grub2-common krb5-locales libgssapi-krb5-2 libido3-0.1-0 libk5crypto3
  libkrb5-3 libkrb5support0 libnautilus-extension1a linux-firmware
  linux-libc-dev nautilus nautilus-data notify-osd-icons unity-settings-daemon
  unzip wpasupplicant
21 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
45 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/78.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 365 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: error: info database format (2) is bogus or too new; try getting a newer dpkg
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Comment: First try: **`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`**

Comment: it doesn't work still getting                 dpkg: error: info database format (2) is bogus or too new; try getting a newer dpkg

Comment: That's a new one. Even Google doesn't have any other hits for this error message.

Comment: Can you provide output from: **`sudo dpkg --configure -a`** and try **`sudo apt-get install -f`** (from: http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1642173.html )

Comment: arun@arun-RD405-L-CDA1A2:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
[sudo] password for arun: 
dpkg: error: info database format (2) is bogus or too new; try getting a newer dpkg

Comment: arun@arun-RD405-L-CDA1A2:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 24 not upgraded.
45 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
dpkg: error: info database format (2) is bogus or too new; try getting a newer dpkg
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)

Comment: this is what i get

Comment: Fixed the problem by replacing   dpkg files in var/lib